# Filter rxjava not work

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

i recently learning RxJava. I am learning about operator. This is my code :

```
tvText = findViewById(R.id.tvText)

val observable2 = Observable.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
observable2.filter { i ->
    //filter genap
    i!!
    i % 2 == 0
}

tvText.setOnClickListener {
    observable2.subscribe(object: Subscriber<Int>() {
        override fun onNext(t: Int?) {
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        override fun onError(e: Throwable?) {
            e!!.printStackTrace()
        }

        override fun onCompleted() {
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    })
}
```

The problem is the filter is not working. The toast show all the number. What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the original `observable2`, not the filtered one. The `filter` function does not modify the `Observable` it is called on but instead returns a new one.

So, to fix your code, save the filter result into a new variable and use it instead of the original observable:

```
val filteredObservable2 = observable2.filter { i ->
    i % 2 == 0
}

tvText.setOnClickListener {
    filteredObservable2.subscribe(object: Subscriber<Int>() {
        /*...*/
    }
}
```